# What is `typing._GenericAlias` in python typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

```py
import typing
assert type(typing.List[int]) == typing._GenericAlias
assert type(list[int]) == typing.GenericAlias
```

I can't find the definition of `typing._GenericAlias` in the python official document.
And what's the difference between `typing._GenericAlias` and `typing.GenericAlias`?

Comment: It starts with underscore, so it's a private implementation detail. If you need the actual explanation of it, I can write an answer with possible usage and reasons to have it.

Comment: Comments in the source, starting from [`_BaseGenericAlias`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L1246) and below, should be hepful.